# Magento 2 Set $_POST to an empty Array()

Tags: forms, magento2.2.2, post-data

I can't seem to find a way to set `$_POST` to an empty array.

I have a form in phtml action to self I can get `$_POST` values the following ways:

```
$this->getRequest()->getPostValue('form_key');

$this->getRequest()->getParam('form_key');
```

The Above will give `Array ( [form_key] => FThdknnc_347djcncKey_)`

Now I've tried to reset by doing:

```
$this->getRequest()->setPostValue('form_key');
```

But it gives me:

```
Array ([form_key] =>)
```

That ain't right browser still popping up saying that it will resend data from form: It should return `Array ()` But the form_key key is still in the `$_POST` Array. one can do in php:

`$_POST = Array();` and that would be enough but it doesn't work with magento.

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/** @var \Zend\Stdlib\ParametersInterface $postParameters */
$postParameters = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
$postParameters->fromArray([]);
```

Use `getQuery` method to clean GET parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
$formKey = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue('form_key');

unset($formKey);
```

than after you can try to set again

```
$this->getRequest()->setPostValue('form_key','your_value');
```

**Hope it helps.**